# Why is reverse wrist curl more difficult as compared to wrist curl?

Tags: exercise, muscle, wrist

Why reverse wrist curl is difficult as compared to wrist curl, I recently started training my wrists and I find it, are muscles for reverse wrist curl weaker by nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrist flexors are stronger than extensors due to differences in muscle compartment composition.  The wrist and finger flexors provide more precise movements, including an additional muscle that's a powerful wrist and finger flexor called the:

---

### Flexor Digitorum Profundus

[image]

---

In contrast, the primary wrist extensor is the **Extensor Digitorum**.  As a matching **Flexor Digitorum** also exists the absence of an *"Extensor Profundus"* results in less precise, weaker wrist Extension.

---

### Extensor Digitorum

[image]

---

***View Free Muscular 3D Model's*** -- *Great Site!*
https://human.biodigital.com